# How to get all intersections between two simple polygons in O(n+k)?

Tags: polygon, algorithm, intersection

Can someone help with a following problem: report all intersections between two simple polygons in [**O(n+k)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_notation) where n - is a total number of polygon edges and k - is number of intersections. As a result - algorithm should output pairwise edges that interesect. It is very important that algorithm should be linear.

I've read that this can be solved in given time with linking to *U. Finke and K. Hinrichs. Overlaying simply connected planar subdivisions in linear time.* But I couldn't find this paper and I'm not even sure that this is my case.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2041.